# Automating R to run scripts

Tags: r, automation, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm basically looking for any way to automatically run R scripts just like it would run as if I was copy and pasting it into console. I've tried the package 'taskscheduleR' however it just seems to output to a log file in the directory which isn't as if I were to just run it inside the Rstudio application.

An example might be, say I want to get the last closing stock prices of 5 stocks each night, then the script in Rstudio and have the variables there and all of the code would be in the script file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest the in-built Task Scheduler application if you using Windows.
Create a task that will run a batchscript file. This batchscript file has only 1 line which executes the Rscript you want. Set it to run each night (or whatever time you want).

I am not that well-versed in linux and MacOS but here's what I know:

Linux has cron. Add a job to crontab with your preferred timing and execute your script `path/to/bin/r /path/to/script.r`

MacOS has Automator + iCal (for scheduling). It also has crontab like Linux.